# Bootstrap Drowdown For Navbar

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, navbar

I currently have a regular navbar but my links are starting to large to hold without a dropdown. I want to bring two links together and make them dropdown. This should some easy points for someone. Here is a screen shot and some code. I'd like to bring `sent messages` and `scheduled messages` together to be one dropdown.

Navbar.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <%= link_to 'Tulip Time Text', root_path, class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo", title: 'Send a Message' %>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li><%= link_to 'Numbers', people_path, title: 'Subscribers' %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Sent Messages', messages_path, title: 'Received' %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Scheduled Messages', scheduled_message_path, title: 'To Be Sent' %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Statistics', subscribed_num_path, title: 'Total Number of Subscribers' %></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-right col-md-4">
  <% if current_user %>
  <li class="col-md-8 user-name">
  <%= link_to ('<i class="fa fa-user"></i> ' + truncate(current_user.email, length: 25)).html_safe,
  edit_user_password_path, title: 'Edit Profile' %>
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-3 logout"><%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path,
  class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger', title: 'Logout', :method => :delete) %></li>
  <% else %>
  <li class="col-md-4 pull-right">
  <%= link_to('Sign In', new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-primary', title: 'Sign In') %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go. Is there a reason you have rows/columns in your navbar? I would probably recommend against that.

It's essentially just a basic [dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns). The only difference is instead of using a `div` tag, you use the `li` tag, because you want this to be within the current unordered list you have already.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><%= link_to 'Sent Messages', messages_path, title: 'Received' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Scheduled Messages', scheduled_message_path, title: 'To Be Sent' %></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Below is the entire navbar, exluding the columns and adding the `collapse` class for mobile displays. Note: You would need to add the hamburger icon/link...see below for html.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <%= link_to 'Tulip Time Text', root_path, class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo", title: 'Send a Message' %>
     </div>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><%= link_to 'Numbers', people_path, title: 'Subscribers' %></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
           </a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><%= link_to 'Sent Messages', messages_path, title: 'Received' %></li>
             <li><%= link_to 'Scheduled Messages', scheduled_message_path, title: 'To Be Sent' %></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><%= link_to 'Statistics', subscribed_num_path, title: 'Total Number of Subscribers' %></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="nav navbar-right">
         <% if current_user %>
           <li class="user-name">
             <%= link_to ('<i class="fa fa-user"></i> ' + truncate(current_user.email, length: 25)).html_safe, edit_user_password_path, title: 'Edit Profile' %>
           </li>
           <li class="logout">
             <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger', title: 'Logout', :method => :delete) %>
           </li>
         <% else %>
           <li class="pull-right">
             <%= link_to('Sign In', new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-primary', title: 'Sign In') %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You'll probably want to add the hamburger icon/link to toggle the navbar on mobile displays...

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

You can see the entire HTML structure of the navbar on Bootstrap 3 [at their docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#default-navbar).